# Commit changes to GitHub does not work after importing project

Tags: android, github

I imported my project from GitHub to my work computer and made some changes to it. But when I tried to commit my changes it just says that there are no changes to commit. How can I fix that? Also, I downloaded the zip to work computer.

Comment: Did you add the files with git add first? Can you show what you were entering in the console? How did you import it, did you clone?

Comment: Did you change files that are ignored by git? As I'm afraid you might be quite new to git, i would suggest reading up on the basics a little (http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) and just play around with a test repo locally to get used to it.

Comment: @ zacharybys -i usually push my projects directly from android stusio.i tried now with clone and git add but it says "not a git repository". And from android studio when i push commit it says i don't have any files to commit

Comment: @Capricorn yes i changed the files.i tried folloowing the basics that you send me but i fail...

Comment: This question might get more response on superuser.com